# Как реализовать в QTreeView (библиотека PyQt5) двойной щелчок левой кнопкой мыши на элементе?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в следующей проблеме.

Имеется приложение, где слева расположен виджет QTreeView с древовидной структурой файлов, а справа текстовое поле QTextEdit.

Как сделать так, чтобы при двойном нажатии левой кнопкой мыши, скажем, на текстовый файл, он открывался бы текстовом поле?

Другими словами, мне нужно получить абсолютный путь к файлу при двойном нажатии на него. Подскажите, как это сделать.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QSplitter, QTreeView, QTextEdit, 
                             QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
import os

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')
        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.splitter = QSplitter()
        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.tree)
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.splitter.setSizes([50, 200])
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.splitter)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)

        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWidget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действия:

- Добавить сигнал [doubleClicked](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked) для обработки двойного клика: `self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self._on_double_clicked)`
- Добавить метод обработки сигнала:

  ```
  def _on_double_clicked(self, index):
      file_name = self.model.filePath(index)

      with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
          text = f.read()
          self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)
  ```

Сигнал [doubleClicked](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#doubleClicked) посылает [индекс](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qmodelindex.html) элемента, а чтобы получить путь по индексу, нужно у [модели](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html) вызвать метод [filePath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#filePath).

---

Полный пример:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import (
    QApplication, QWidget, QSplitter, QTreeView, QTextEdit,
    QFileSystemModel, QVBoxLayout, QDir
)
import os


class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Direct tree')

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())

        self.tree = QTreeView()
        self.tree.setModel(self.model)
        self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))
        self.tree.doubleClicked.connect(self._on_double_clicked)
        self.tree.setAnimated(False)
        self.tree.setIndentation(20)
        self.tree.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()

        splitter = QSplitter()
        splitter.addWidget(self.tree)
        splitter.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        splitter.setSizes([50, 200])

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(splitter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

    def _on_double_clicked(self, index):
        file_name = self.model.filePath(index)

        with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as f:
            text = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setPlainText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])

    win = MyWidget()
    win.resize(600, 400)
    win.show()

    app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]